# Perguntas interessantes apresentando boa reputação com várias respostas possíveis

Tags: debate, fechamento

Além de mim mais 3 usuários favoritaram e outros 5 votaram a favor dessa pergunta: [Como é realizado testes de software](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92086/como-%C3%A9-realizado-testes-de-software)

Porém a mesma foi considerada com muitas respostas possíveis e que boas respostas seriam muito extensas.

Gostaria de saber se uma pergunta interessante como essa, com tantos votos positivos e usuários que favoritaram não poderia continuar aberta apesar de possuir várias respostas possíveis, além de apresentar comentários na própria pergunta favoráveis a colocar uma resposta na pergunta. Apesar de gerar várias respostas possíveis, boas e longas acredito que seria útil e que uma excessão poderia vir a ser aberta nesses casos em que existe uma grande procura e boa reputação.

Comment: O assunto é interessante, mas a pergunta tem pelo menos dois problemas: ela generaliza ("os grandes sites"), e fala de mais de um tipo de teste (do código, e aparentemente de UX, quando fala dos testes A/B na segunda parte). Se alguém corrigir esses problemas, por edição e provavelmente desmembramento em duas perguntas, aí sim poderia render boas respostas.

Comment: Uma pergunta legal ou interessante não é necessariamente uma boa pergunta. Muitas vezes é preciso lapidar a questão para chegar a uma boa qualidade. O assunto questionado é muito extenso e existem várias técnicas para atacar o problema usados diferente em cada tipo de sistema e de forma diferente dependendo da empresa e do público alvo.

Comment: Espero realmente que a pergunta seja um pouco mais focada pois gostaria de respondê-la. :)

Comment: Estranho tanto usuários votaram a favor, mas ninguém votou pra reabrir... quer dizer que tem problema no meio dela (que eu não faço ideia do que seja :P ), talvez se o autor editar votem por reabrir.

Answer (score 5):

O autor fez uma edição e deixou a pergunta bem melhor. Ela foi reaberta.

Comment: Acabei de observar @bfavaretto, obrigado.

Comment: Mesmo que eu ache a pergunta boa, não me parece uma "boa pergunta para o StackOverFlow". Eu estou acostumado com o StackOverFlow em inglês, onde este tipo de pergunta seria rejeitada. Isso acotece, pois aqui seria um espaço para tirarmos dúvidas, quando temos um bug, ou um problema que não conseguimos solucionar, e este tipo de pergunta é muito subjetiva, tem muitas respostas possíveis e nunhuma estará realmente certa ou errada. Tem muita filosofia nas respostas.  Acho que o  "pt.StarOverFlow" está tratando este tipo de pergunta diferente do que o "StackOverFlow.com".

Comment: Oi @FernandoMondo. Existem mesmo diferenças entre o site em inglês e o nosso, mas nenhum dos dois é só para "quando temos um bug, ou um problema que não conseguimos solucionar". Isso é um mal-entendido comum nos dois sites, especialmente lá, onde os mal-entendidos se espalham mais rapidamente. Perguntas conceituais são aceitas em ambos. Perguntas subjetivas também, se forem [construídas adequadamente](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/486). Sobre esta pergunta específica, tirando a parte do "bem"/"boa maneira", depois da edição ela passou a ser bem objetiva. [continua...]

Comment: Sobre as respostas que a pergunta recebeu, você acha mesmo que tenham "muita filosofia"? Elas são parcialmente conceituais, mas isso não é problema. Pelo contrário, os conceitos, em programação, são fundamentais. Quem trata código sem dominar os conceitos subjacentes certamente terá problemas. E veja que as respostas são apenas *parcialmente* conceituais, porque testar software é um coisa bem concreta. As respostas tratam de procedimentos.

Comment: Não quis dizer sobre esta perguunta especificamente, mas sim em um âmbito geral. E eu afirmo sobre este tipo de pergunta não ser aceita lá, pois algumas de minhas próprias perguntas não foram aceitas. Porém, me foi aconselhado lá, a postar no http://programmers.stackexchange.com que é mais aberto a este tipo de pergunta. Você pode conferir no http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic nos tipos de perguntas aceitas e no item 4 das perguntas off-topic. Mas só para deixar claro, eu gosto deste tipo de pergunta, por mim não teria problema, só acho que não é o estilo do site mesmo aceitar,

Comment: @FernandoMondo Quem faz o estilo do site é a comunidade. Existem muito poucos *tipos* de perguntas que não são aceitos em nenhum site da rede. A maioria deles tem pelo menos 1 site que acredita que elas podem ser úteis lá, e tentam encontrar uma forma de fazer com que as perguntas sejam cabíveis e aceitas lá. Até as famigeradas "recomendação de compras". Não quer dizer que tudo tem que ser aceito em todos os sites, mas sim que eles tem liberdade quase plena para decidir o que é importante, e trabalhar na manutenção da sua qualidade.